# Trying to to solve the ‘dog chasing rabbit’ problem with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

When I type the following into Mathematica, it just returns it back to me unchanged:

```
DSolve[{y'[t] == (y[t] - v t) x'[t]/x[t], y'[t]^2 + x'[t]^2 == u^2}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

`x[t]` and `y[t]` are coordinates of the dog whose speed is `u` and whose velocity is always directed at the rabbit whose position is v*t on the y-axis.

How can I get Mathematica to solve this?

Comment: Do you need symbolic or numerical solution ? Is it "Pursuit Curve" problem that you are looking for ?

Comment: [This paper](http://sections.maa.org/okar/papers/2006/lloyd.pdf) (using Maple) suggests that the problem will have to be solved by numerical methods.

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem must be solved numerically. Here is how I did it.

```
{xF, yF} =
  With[{u = 1, v = 8/10, ϵ = 1/10},
    NDSolveValue[
      {y'[t] == (y[t] - v t) x'[t]/x[t], (y'[t])^2 + (x'[t])^2 == u^2, 
       x[0] == 5, y[0] == 0, WhenEvent[Abs[y[t] - v t] < ϵ, "StopIntegration"]},
      {x, y}, {t, 0, ∞}]];

With[{tmax = xF["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, 
  ParametricPlot[{xF[t], yF[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]]
```

[image: plot]

The quantity `ϵ` is taken to be the distance along the y-axis between dog and the rabbit at which the dog is close enough to catch the rabbit.